# How do I type a special character on top of a character in java(FX)

Tags: java, unicode, javafx

A dot on top of a variable denotes its derivative with time and A double dot is its second derivative with time.
I want to type this on a JavaFX pane. How do I do that??

PS-essentially the equivalent of \dot{x} in latex.

Comment: If you want any letter, probably you have to create the graphic of the glyph by yourself, because there is no character encoding that supports all (latin) letters with dot(s). If you can use an unicode font, probably you will be able to insert this characters into a WebView, [like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) `&euml;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out myself. Posting it here for the benefit of others.

This is how you do it.
the Unicode for typing a (.) on top of a Character is `\u0307`. Append this to any character you want and you will get a (.) on top of it.

Eg:

```
String pbDot = "P\u0307b";
String omegaDot = "\u03C9\u0307";
```

Result:

[image]